# checking whether a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Let $n \ge 2$, $\lambda_i>0$, $i=1,2,\cdots, n$. Let $\Lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$. Let $$a_{ij}=\begin{cases}\Lambda-\lambda_i\quad &i=j\\
\Lambda-\lambda_i-\lambda_j\quad &i\ne j\end{cases}$$
My question is that, is $(a_{ij})$ a positive definite matrix? I have checked the case $n=2$ and $n=3$ by direct computations for determinants of all leading principle minors, and found out that the answer is positive. However, when $n\ge 4$, the computation is very complicated and I cannot see the sign. I'm wondering are there any simpler ways to see that $(a_{ij})$ is positive definite? Any comments or ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: See if you can show $x{_i}a_{ij}x_{j}>0, \forall x_{i} \neq 0$. It seems to be possible.

Comment: Let $p_i=\frac{\lambda_i}{\Lambda}$ and $e$ be the vector of ones. Then $A=\Lambda\left(\operatorname{diag}(p)+ee^T-ep^T-pe^T\right)$, and $x^TAx=\Lambda\left[\operatorname{var}_p(X)+\left(nE(X)-E_p(X)\right)^2\right]$.

Comment: @user1551, thank you very much!